# MySQL. Внешние ключи. Ошибка при создании таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Почему то не работает команда

```
CREATE table Marriage (
        serial_num_husband varchar(30) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES People(serial_number_passport),
        serial_num_wife varchar(30) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES People(serial_number_passport));
```

Выдает ошибку

> A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "FOREIGN KEY" at position 71)
>   Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "serial_number_passport" at position 101)
>   Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "serial_num_wife" at position 133)
>
> > P.S. Есть таблица `People` которая имеет `PRIMARY KEY`  serial_number_passport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
CREATE table Marriage (   
    serial_num_husband varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    serial_num_wife varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (serial_num_husband) REFERENCES People(serial_number_passport),
    FOREIGN KEY (serial_num_wife) REFERENCES People(serial_number_passport)
)
```

Comment: вы совершенно правы )) посмотрел в инете поискал и нашел что для разных СУБД синтаксис разный и оказывается в MySQL пишется так как вы написали )